# Unable to load the string into objects using json.loads

Tags: python, json, oop

I am trying to load a string into python object. I am getting below error: 
This is error :  Expecting value: line 15 column 15 (char 351)
{'allData': None}

When I change the value for cprob to below code, there is no issue:

```
    "cprob": {
        "T": 1,
        "A": 2,
        "C": 3
        }
```

Data in test.txt:

```
[{
        "V": ["Offer", "Interview", "Grades", "Admission", "Experience"],
    "E": [["Grades", "Interview"],
        ["Experience", "Interview"],
        ["Grades", "Admission"],
        ["Interview", "Offer"]],
    "Vdata": {
        "Offer": {
            "ord": 4,
            "numoutcomes": 2,
            "vals": ["0", "1"],
            "parents": ["Interview"],
            "children": 0,
            "cprob": {
                "['0']": [.9, .1],
                "['1']": [.4, .6],
                "['2']": [.01, .99]
                }
            }
        }
}]
```

Code:

```
import json
class JsonData: 

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.allData = None 

    def dictload(self, path):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        ftext = f.read() 
        print(ftext)
        try: 
            self.allData = json.loads(ftext)
        except Exception as e:
            print('This is error : ', e)

path = "test.txt"

jsonData = JsonData(path)
jsonData.dictload(path)
print(vars(jsonData))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems python's json module doesn't understand `.1` to be `0.1`. If you add the `0` in front of the period it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much. What a simple solution. Great it works. forum say, I can accept the answer in 8 mins :)

Comment: @NagaVemprala alternatively use the `ast` module; `with open('test.txt') as f: d = ast.literal_eval(f.read())`

Comment: @Chris_Rands ast.literal_eval works beautifully too. Thank you. I dont think I will go for json.loads again

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Javascript's JSON.parse can't parse it neither. However `jq` can. The [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) say "A number is a sequence of decimal digits with no superfluous leading zero." but the graphic shows a `0` before the period so it seems to be necessary.